# how to use spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, autoload, spl

I am just learning how to use spl_autoload_register

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
lib/projectname/home/homepage.php
```

so if I include the file like this it works:

```
include("lib/projectname/home/homepage.php");
$home = new homepage();
```

I have added in an autoload.php file which looks like this:

```
function myclass($class_name) {
   $class_name = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name) . '.php';
   require_once($class_name);
 }

spl_autoload_register('myclass');
```

Now if I try to use the class I am referencing it like this:

```
require_once("autoload.php");

$home = new lib_projectname_home_homepage;
```

when i do this, i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'lib_projectname_home_homepage' not found
```

So it appears as if the loading of the class file is working, but its not finding the class inside the file?

The actual homepage.php file looks like this:

```
class homepage {

    function __construct(){

        echo "homepage";
    }

}
```

What do I need to change in order to make this work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
class homepage {
    function __construct(){
        echo "homepage";
    }
}
```

to

```
class lib_projectname_home_homepage {
    function __construct(){
        echo "homepage";
    }
}
```

or change:

```
require_once($class_name);
```

to

```
require_once('lib/projectname/home/' . $class_name);
```

and then:

```
$home = new homepage();
```

concept of autoloader is simply to find class with a given name. it does not change class name on the fly.